# EKF-SLAM, how best to manage the 'P' covariance matrix, programatically

Tags: slam, ekf, python

I've recently been learning about SLAM and EKF-SLAM.

I've began my implementation in python, but have had trouble managing the updating of P, especially when it comes to adding new landmarks. Currently there is no 'P' but just a few separate matrices that I have to stitch together when needed.

My implementation can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/r7wUMgY7

How best should I manage the large covariance matrix, should I be using one matrix, like the algorithm suggests? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use one matrix, because you must manage the cross covariances. The best way to add a landmark is to expand the matrix, by copying it into a larger one (with two extra rows for x,y and two extra columns for the same). Then, you have to initialize all the off-diagonal terms using the jacobian matrix.  Similarly, the state vector must be expanded to include the new landmark as well.

[This answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/5173/163) shows how to initialize a new landmark in this way.  Note the matrix shown there is *block* represented. It could in fact be very large.

Now how you represent that matrix is up to you. However, keeping many small matrices that you stitch together is no more efficient (cpu or memory) than keeping one large one.

Comment: Fair point and thanks for the link. I'll most likely go for the 'initialise big empty matrix' approach.